# SOLID, Does Liskov Substitution Principle (LSP) conflict with the Interface Segregation Principle (ISP)?

Tags: object-oriented, interfaces, solid, liskov-substitution

I am confused by the two principles of SOLID, liskovs substitution principle and interface segregation principle. It seem as though they conflict each other's definitions.

How can a class that implements interfaces also guarenttee that it also fits the liksov subsitution?

For example, in this code, if a client to make a new shape class they must still implement IDraw and IMove. Therefore, doesn't that make the concept of ISP nullified since it states that:

> "A client should never be forced to implement an interface that it doesn't use or clients shouldn't be forced to depend on methods they do not use."

```
    // In this example all clients **must** implement IDraw() and IMove()

    public interface IDraw
    {
        void Draw();
    }
    
    public interface IMove
    {
        void Move();
    }
    
    public abstract class Shape : IDraw, IMove
    {
        public abstract void Draw();
        public abstract void Move();
    }
    
    public class Square : Shape
    {
        public override void Draw()
        {
        }
        public override void Move()
        {
        }
    }
    
    public class Rectangle : Shape
    {
        public override void Draw()
        {
        }
        public override void Move()
        {
        }
    }
```

Alternatively, if I put interfaces "halfway" in the class heirachy, LSP is nullified but now ISP is preserved, for example:

```
// In this example the classes Rectangle and Square are no longer interchangeable, so LSP is broken. 

using System;

public interface IDraw
{
    void Draw();
}

public interface IMove
{
    void Move();
}

public abstract class Shape
{
}

public class Square : Shape, IDraw
{
    public void Draw()
    {
    }
}

public class Rectangle : Shape, IMove
{
    public void Move()
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you misunderstand - a 'client' is the code which **uses** the interface (interacts with objects) from the outside (e.g. calls its methods), and not the class(es) which *implement* the interface.    i.e.  `Shape`/`Square`/`Rectangle` are not clients of `IDraw` or `IMove` because they aren't the ones actually interacting with objects via the interface.

Comment: @BenCottrell But the quote says "A client should never be forced to implement an interface...", does implement here mean inherit and implement?

edit - oh i notice now that the statement differs depending on the source! wikipedia says "no client should be forced to depend on methods it does not use" whereas the one from above says OR implements.etc

Comment: @BenCottrell I think i'm seeing where you come from: from https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwhCYaYDn8EgOTViYjJhYzMtMzYxMC00MzFjLWJjMzYtOGJiMDc5N2JkYmJi/view it says "CLIENTS SHOULD NOT BE FORCED TO DEPEND UPON INTERFACES
THAT THEY DO NOT USE." and if clients are users of its interface then that makes sense, since inherited classes aren't clients.

Comment: @BenCottrell: I agree with your definition of "client" but the referenced quote doesn't use that definition. It specifically talks about clients _implementing_ an interface, not "clients handling an object of an interface's type". I think the confusion can be avoided if the quote was rephrased to use "consumer".

Comment: I'm not sure why this question is being downvoted. While OP may have a lacking understanding of the principles in focus (_hence the question_), the question is clear, understandable and well-formed.

Comment: I think this is a confusing example to demonstrate ISP. It is not clear (from the real world) why a Square can be drawn, but a Rectangle cannot. 
Maybe a better example would be a Square and a Line and the methods setFillingColour and setLength. Both objects have a length you can set, but setting the filling colour just doesn't make any sense for a Line and should be extracted into a different interface.

Comment: Please just ignore this phrase "A client should never be forced to implement an interface that it doesn't use or clients shouldn't be forced to depend on methods they do not use." It is meaningless, even if you substitute client with consumer or whatever. What they probably want to say is that it is better to have multiple small interfaces defining distinct behaviors than to have one big interface that defines a combination of behaviors because there will be classes to which not all behaviors are relevant. Classes should be able to pick and choose what behaviors to implement. This is ISP.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Alternatively, if I put interfaces "halfway" in the class hierarchy, LSP is nullified

> ```
> classes Rectangle and Square are no longer interchangeable
> ```

Yes and no. Some things are mixed up here. And some are omitted.

### mixed up stuff

[LSP according to wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle)

> if S is a subtype of T, then objects of type T in a program may be replaced with objects of type S without altering any of the desirable properties of that program

LSP is not concerned about two sibling types `Rectangle` and `Square` being interchangeable with each other. It's concerned about interchangeability of a `supertype` and one of its `subtype`.

LSP in code is basically this:

```
Shape shape = new Rectangle(); // should be OK to treat a rectangle like a shape
Shape shape = new Square(); // should be OK to treat a square like a shape
```

In a sense, you could say that `Rectangle` and `Square` are *interchangeable* here, both being possible substitutions for `Shape`, but this is merely a result of LSP relationships of `Rectangle` and `Square` to their superclass `Shape` respectively.

Every type has an individual LSP relationship to each of its supertypes. So given `Square : Shape, IDraw` and `Rectangle : Shape, IMove` the above is still valid:

```
Shape shape = new Rectangle(); // still OK to treat a rectangle like a shape
Shape shape = new Square(); // still OK to treat a square like a shape
```

What you are likely referring to as a sign of non-interchangeability of `Rectangle` and `Square` is that you cannot do this:

```
IDraw draw = new Rectangle(); // nope
IMove move = new Square(); // nope
```

But there's no `supertype`-`subtype` relationship between `IDraw` and `Rectangle` / `IMove` and
`Square` respectively, which means LSP isn't nullified here, it simply doesn't apply. Expecting interchangeability here is "begging the question". LSP still applies to each `supertype`-`subtype` relationship individually:

```
IDraw draw = new Square(); // ok
IMove move = new Rectangle(); // ok
```

Just because `Rectangle` and `Square` have one common supertype `Shape`, which according to LSP they are each individually interchangeable with, does not (necessarily) mean they are *interchangeable* with each other.

This sort of LSP interchangeability explained above is fulfilled by the type-system already, because every subtype is also all its supertypes. There's more to this than just types.

### comment

> But given that `Rectangle` uses `IDraw` and `Square` uses `IMove`, how do you abide by LSP when replacing it with the base class `Shape`, since shape doesn't use `IDraw` or `IMove`?

The LSP relationship has a "direction". You can use a `subtype` where a `supertype` is expected, but not the other way round.

If you have a `Rectangle` object in place somewhere in your code and you use `Draw` of `IDraw`, then you are correct that you could not substitute that with `Shape` object, "*since shape doesn't use `IDraw`*". **This expectation however is unreasonable or simply wrong in terms of LSP.** LSP is not suggesting that you can do this.

Again, you are begging the question by asking "how do I abide by LSP if I do something that doesn't".

As a rule of thumb: **You cannot break LSP with just the type system, because the hierarchical type system is equivalent to LSP.**

### omitted stuff

The actually important thing about LSP is not types, but behaviour.
Your example is entirely free from any functionality and concentrates on compatibility of types. All your methods are empty.

There's always an "implicit" part to a type definition. Sometimes this is referred to as an "implicit contract". This includes things like:

- Under which conditions will this method throw an exception?
- What properties/variables/fields (more general: what *members*) of the class are expected to be updated after calling a method?

Here's a modified example of your code:

```
public interface IDraw
{
    void Draw(); // draw object into the buffer
    DrawingBuffer GetBuffer();
}
```

This new version of `IDraw` demands that you update the drawing buffer to be retrieved later.

***disclaimer**: Whether this sort of interface design is a good idea or not is questionable. It might be perfectly fine or it might be better to have only one method: `DrawingBuffer Draw();` For the sake of this explanation, let's assume it is the way to go.*

Now - strictly speaking - the code as is **breaks** LSP, because it is not updating the buffer:

```
public class Square : Shape
{
    public override void Draw()
    {
         // not updating the buffer here
    }
    public override void Move()
    {
    }
}
```

And it's the same with the other one:

```
public class Square : Shape, IDraw
{
    public void Draw()
    {
        // not updating the buffer here
    }
}
```

Of course, if actually updating the buffer is *optional*, this is might be ok to opt-out for implementation of special cases, like if the shape hasn't changed.

But when it comes to Exceptions, you might accidentally opt-in, where you shouldn't:

```
public interface IMove
{
    void Move(); // don't throw exception here
}


public class Rectangle : Shape, IMove
{
    public void Move()
    {
         _x = screenSize / _somePrivateVariableThatMightBeZero;
    }
}
```

Depending on your programming language, types of `_x`, `screenSize`  and `_somePrivateVariableThatMightBeZero` and the value of the latter, the above code might throw an exception due to a division by 0;

This breaks the contract of `IMove` and thus LSP.
A user of `IMove` would expect to be able to call `Move()` without having to deal with (likely implementation specific) exceptions being thrown.

Comment: But given that Rectangle uses IDraw and Square uses IMove, how do you abide by LSP when replacing it with the base class Shape, since shape doesn't use IDraw or IMove?

Comment: @RichardBamford that pain is entirely caused by the fact that your model doesn't make any sense - why can only rectangles be drawn? Why can only squares be moved? The LSP only matters at the level of the interface being consumed - anything that claims it implements `IDraw` should be interchangeable from the perspective of a consumer of that interface.

Comment: @RichardBamford I edited my answer. In short: you don't abide LSP when replacing `Rectangle` with `Shape`. But this is not possible either (the type system does not allow it), which is because the type system is based on LSP.

Comment: Ooh! i think this is where my error in logic is, i thought that LSP was bidirectional! Thanks :)

Answer (score 5):

### Do LSP and ISP contradict one another?

No. These principles actually work in tandem, or at least part of their problem domain overlaps and tackles a similar issue.

You could generalize them into the "don't claim and/or pretend to be something you're not" principle, as that sort of gets at the core issue that either of them focuses on.

But to be fair, it may be easier to observe them separately. I'm going to call it the Principle Separation Principle or PSP :-)

---

### Which example is correct?

Your example is a bit nonsensical. The code is legible, but which version of the code is correct is a business decision. Depending on those contextual decisions, the correctness of the code is decided

**Should every `Shape` be both drawable and movable?**

If yes, then the first example is correct. The second example is demonstrably incorrect then, as you wouldn't be able to draw or move a `Shape` object.

If no, then the second example is correct, assuming that shapes should only be drawable (not movable) and rectangles should only be movable (not drawable).

In the "no" case, the first example would then be a violation of LSP, as you're ending up with classes who (indirectly) implement an interface they have no intention of actually complying with (rectangles don't want to be drawn, squares don't want to be moved)

More importantly, **you cannot judge LSP/ISP here without knowing the business requirements**.

---

### How do you violate or comply with LSP/ISP?

Your current interpretation of what LSP and ISP aim to solve are not correct. They're in the right direction, but misapplied.

**LSP**

LSP effectively states that when a type inherits/implements a base type/interface, it must therefore behave exactly like that base type/interface claims to behave.

In your examples, the clearest example is that when you state that `Shape : IMove`, then **every** derived `Shape` must comply with that `IMove` contract. If it doesn't, it violates LSP.

Maybe a clearer way of looking at it is that LSP would be violated if you implemented your `IDraw`/`IMove` interfaces in such a way that some derived `Shape` classes would have to implement duds (i.e. they choose to not move, or not be drawn). Whether that dud is an empty method body, throws an exception, or does something completely unrelated; is irrelevant here - it's an LSP violation in all three cases.

Note also that LSP predominantly explains itself using inheritance between classes, as opposed to interface implementation. However, I don't see a reason to make this distinction when considering good practice, as the problem domain is effectively the same whether your base type is a class or an interface.

**ISP**

ISP effectively states that independent "features" should be separated because they are independent, so they don't have to carry each other as baggage.

If in your codebase your want to have objects that are movable-but-not-drawable, or drawable-but-not-movable, then you should have separate `IDraw` and `IMove` interfaces so they can be independently apply to one another.
This also applies to "obvious" cases, where you are still advised to separate two obviously independent behaviors even if you currently happen to always apply both (or neither) of them to your objects. The question here is whether they logically *always* belong together or not. In the latter case, interface segregation is warranted.

Your examples don't actually include any ISP violations, as you always deal with separate `IMove` and `IDraw` interfaces.

If you were to merge these into a `IDrawAndMove` interface, and some of the classes implementing that interface would be trying to do one and not the other (i.e. movable-but-not-drawable, or drawable-but-not-movable), then that would be an ISP violation as you should instead separate your interface into `IDraw` and `IMove` and independently apply them to the classes that actually *want* to comply with them.

Comment: thanks! i have one question though, if i use seperate IDraw and IMove, doesn't that nullify the LSP since one can't replace Rectangle and Square with Shape and then back to either?

Comment: "you cannot judge LSP/ISP here without knowing the business requirements" – This. Especially for the LSP, the (somewhat simplified) definition is "For all properties `p` provable about a program `P`, an instance `s` of a type `S <: T` should be substitutable for an instance of `T` without removing any property from the set of provable properties." Or something like that. A more colloquial formulation would be "substituting an instance of a subtype for an instance of a super type doesn't change the desirable properties of the program". Which should make it immediately obvious, that *before* we

Comment: … even *begin* to talk about the LSP, we *first* need to define what the "desirable properties" even are.

Comment: @RichardBamford: You can, in fact, interchangeably use a `Square` or `Rectangle` whenever there is a `Shape` variable/method parameter. But if you don't define a `Shape` itself as `IMove`, then your logic could never expect to be able to move that `Shape`, **regardless** of whether the derived `Shape` class (e.g. `Rectangle`) implements it or not. If your method requires anything that can be moved, use the `IMove` type. If it requires anything that's a shape, use the `Shape` type. Ask what you need - and don't expect to get anything else as you won't be guaranteed to get it.

Comment: @RichardBamford - you have to consider these principles in context of what you're designing for. LSP is about substitutability, ISP is about other code not being dependent on a bloated class. If the problem you're trying to solve requires that all your shapes can be drawn and can move, then it's fine for all of them to implement those two interfaces; in fact, in that case you don't even need the separate interfaces, they don't serve any purpose; having only the abstract Shape class is fine. 1/3

Comment: @RichardBamford - But consider now a different case. Let's say that the Square, the Rectangle, the Circle, etc. all move differently (e.g., maybe a rectangle can only move horizontally and vertically, and the steps it takes depend on its width and height, while the circle can go in any direction). Suppose now that, for some reason, you need to implement something that moves like a rectangle, but draw a small circle in its place (maybe you're making some tool that helps you debug visually, like a game developer would). How would you go about implementing that?  2/3

Comment: @RichardBamford - One flexible way to do it is to keep the interfaces (ISP), and change your clients (consumers, calling code) to look something like this: `ProcessShape(IMove movable, IDraw drawable)`. Then you can call it like this `ProcessShape(rectangle, circle)`, or, if you want to draw a rectangle `ProcessShape(rectangle, rectangle)` (looks strange, but it isn't). You'd probably have to rethink the Draw method - e.g., maybe it should take a location. The point is, consider SOLID in light of the actual requirements, and decide where and how far to apply it based on that. 3/3

Comment: @FilipMilovanović: Minor niggle: "all shapes need to be drawable and movable" != "all movable and drawable things are shapes". The interfaces may still need to exist if other classes intend to implement them too (whether separately or merged into one interface).

Comment: @Flater - I agree, generally speaking, that's true. But my point was that, while you can reasonably predict, to some extent, what elements the design should incorporate, avoid relying *too much* on what *might* be (people often come up with interfaces just because they think that's just something good designers do, without asking themselves what purpose those interfaces serve). Now, sure, if the system already has (or is expected to have) other kinds of drawable and movable objects, the interfaces aren't redundant; what's more, their clients probably already use them separately.

Comment: @FilipMilovanović: This is related to the [Rule Of Three](https://wiki.c2.com/?RuleOfThree), which says you can't build an abstraction until you have three independent clients. There is a nice example of parallel evolution of this: both Eclipse and Visual Studio have a plugin API for version control systems. Both of these APIs were designed so that they support *any* version control system. Both of these were designed when CVS was the dominant vendor-independent version control system. And it turns out that both of these APIs indeed for for *any* version control system … provided that that …

Comment: … version control system is Subversion, which was of course developed by former CVS developers. Both of these APIs caused major pain for the developers of Monotone, Mercurial, Git, Bazaar, Darcs, and co, to the point where we didn't have good plugins for any of those systems for many, many years, until both of those APIs were redesigned. In fact, the plugin API in Visual Studio didn't even work for Microsoft's *own* Team Foundation Server, the successor to Microsoft's Visual Source Safe. Here, we have an example of two abstractions for the same purpose, developed independently, failing similar

Comment: @JörgWMittag - Nice example! Yeah, I had something like the Rule of Three in mind. We have a couple of these design heuristics that are meant to prevent us from making the wrong assumptions too soon - e.g. it's a part of the motivation behind YAGNI.

Comment: @JörgWMittag A variation on the rule of three, I generally refer to it as "counting like a caveman", i.e [one, two, many]. Many should be abstracted.

Comment: @Flater: There is actually also a rule called the [Zero One Infinity Rule](https://wiki.c2.com/?ZeroOneInfinityRule), although that doesn't talk about clients of an abstraction: "Allow none of foo, one of foo, or any number of foo."

Comment: @JörgWMittag & Flater: To me it looks like the common theme here is that we should let go of the idea that you should try and get the design completely right from the start. Instead (1) exercise some restraint to leave your options open (e.g., don't generalize on too few examples), and (2) observe what's going on as the actual code changes, so that you can react (restructure/refactor) in a timely manner, to approach the right design as you go along. One side of the coin is baking in the wrong assumptions too soon, the other is that we tend to miss this window where it pays to course-correct.

Answer (score 1):

Well yes, your example violates these principles, since it doesn't really do anything. If methods are never used at all, they should be removed. That's not the point of the SOLID principles though. The point is that in a real world example, either Shape or one of its subclasses would actually need to be drawable and thus would need an implementation of draw() somewhere. The question then is: *Where is this requirement located in the class hierarchy*?

If all subclasses of Shape are supposed to be drawable, then Shape should implement the IDraw interface (which should be renamed to IDrawable), even if it makes the draw() method abstract, because it lacks specific knowledge on how to draw. But it would probably use the draw() method somewhere else and rely on its concrete subclasses to provide the specific implementation of it. This is way it becomes a (compiler-enforced) part of the contract of the Shape class that Shapes are always drawable.

If not all Shapes are supposed to be movable, then it should not implement the IMove interface (which should be renamed to IMoveable). Instead an intermediate class should implement it, say MoveableShape, which should probably only implement IMoveable if it actually uses the move() method somewhere else in its code. Now it is part of the contract that MoveableShapes are moveable (in addition to being drawable).

The ISP advises you that you should separate interfaces that do separate things, like moving and drawing. This is exactly because if they are separate things, the requirement for where in the class hierarchy they should apply will likely be different and therefore you need different interfaces so classes can be defined with the most appropriate set of interfaces for them. They will only implement what they actually need for their function. And this is even true if the separate things are still related in one direction, say if the move() method is supposed to call the draw() method to update the drawn image on the screen after the internal position state has changed. Then the draw()-part is still of independent value without the move-method and should be segregated into a separate interface.

The Substitution principle plays very well with this scenario: If any Shape-instance should be replaceable by any Square-instance, then obviously Square-instances need to be drawable too. Happily, this is already guaranteed by the rules of inheritance of the programming language (I hope), because Square will inherit the draw() method from Shape. Assuming that Square is a concrete class, then it is forced to provide an implementation for this method to fulfil its contract.

If Squares are not necessarily movable, but Circles are, then Circle should inherit from MoveableShape instead. Again, the substitution principle is satisfied: Every time you see an object with declared type Shape, you can rely on it being drawable, so it could be a Square or a Circle. But you can't and shouldn't rely on it being moveable. But if you see a MovableShape somewhere, you can rest assured that you can call the move() method on it and it will have an implementation for it.

Comment: Yes i think i understand your solution and i think i will use this technique of an intermediate class but then isn't LSP broken between Shape and MoveableShape?

Comment: No. If the contract of Shape says it must be drawable and the contract of MoveableShape says it must be drawable and moveable, then you can use a MovableShape where is Shape is expected, since MovableShape satisfies all the conditions of Shape. Note that not implementing a certain interface like IMoveable doesn't mean that Shape is *forbidden* to be movable, it only means that you cannot rely on it being movable.